# java.util.logging.Logger prints the Message twice in console

Tags: java, logging

I am running a jar file in a console and I put logger so I can trace the if there are any errors. However, the message info prints twice in the console. Can I prevent this?

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Logger");
     log.setLevel(Level.ALL);

     ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
     handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
     handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
     log.addHandler(handler);

     log.log(Level.INFO, "Reading Configuration File");

 }
```

Console:

```
Jul 22, 2015 9:30:33 PM com.ouc.mv90.conversion.CSVtoMV90Converter main
INFO: Reading Configuration File
Jul 22, 2015 9:30:33 PM com.ouc.mv90.conversion.CSVtoMV90Converter main
INFO: Reading Configuration File
```

Comment: You're getting it twice because of adding a ConsoleHandler, the Logger you're getting already have console handler added to it.

Answer (score 16):

Get ready for a facepalm.  This question is basically a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013393/java-logger-console-stream-duplicate-output), but I am giving an answer anyway.

What is happening is that your `Logger` class already has a default handler which prints to the `System.out` console.  I expect that just the following code will generate output in your console:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Logger");
log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
log.log(Level.INFO, "Reading Configuration File");
```

But you have gone above and beyond this by adding a *second* handler which also is directed towards the console.  Remove this second handler and that should take care of duplicate messages.

Answer (score 13):

I have run into this problem and in my case the solution was:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Logger");
ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

Notice the last line that calls to `setUseParentHandlers`. Without this line I get duplicate logs. I have checked at run time that in my case the number of handlers returned by `logger.getHandlers()` is just 1 after adding my console handler.

If I try

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Logger");
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reading Configuration File");
logger.log(Level.FINE, "another message");
```

in this case I don't get duplicate logs but I don't get anything finer than INFO level either.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove all handlers before add it to your logger, like :

```
for (Handler handler : logger.getHandlers()) {  logger.removeHandler(handler);}
```

Comment: fun reset(rootHandler: Handler?) {
                val rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("")
                val handlers = rootLogger.handlers
                for (handler in handlers) {
                    rootLogger.removeHandler(handler)
                }
                rootLogger.addHandler(rootHandler)
            }

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Logger");
     log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
     log.log(Level.INFO, "Reading Configuration File");

 }
```

The above code itself is sufficient to print your log once with it's default log handler. When you add handlers, it will only print in the console using it's default handler, the logging is also directed to your all added handlers to print. Since  you are adding another console handler to your logger, veerything will get printed (logged on the console)  twice.